# How to get same set records populated twice for 2 different default values

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

`Select name,adrs,state, Case when T2.city Is Not null Then T2.City When T2.city = 'uae' then 'U', 'E' else T2.state end end as City_code From DB.TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE2 T2) ON T1.SK = T2.SK;`

As per the above logic, I want the result set to be as below. Say if we are getting 10 records as per the above condition and out of 10 records, 2 records has city has 'uae' in Table2, then I want the result to be populated twice with same name,same adrs, same state but with different city_code that is 'u' and 'e', that is one set of record with 'u' as city_code and another same set with 'e' as city_code.I know that the case when condition is incorrect in the 2nd when condition, but for a better understanding, I gave it that way. Please help with this logic. Thanks in advance!

```
Name  adrs  state  city_code
----  ----  -----  ---------
Adrew oak    TN    U
Adrew oak    TN    E
```

```
Name  adrs  state  city_code
----  ----  -----  ---------
Adrew oak    TN    U
Adrew oak    TN    E
```

Above is the expected result

Answer (score 0):

See below example

```
with test_data as (
  select 'Name1' name, 'uae' city, 'adrs1' adrs, 'state1' state union all
  select 'Name2', 'notuae', 'adrs2', 'state2' 
)
select * from test_data,
unnest(case when city = 'uae' then ['U', 'E'] else [state] end) city_code
```

with output

[image]